# preposition phrase act as a noun

Tags: grammar

> Federal Reserve chair Jay Powell has warned that a full US economic recovery may **take until the end of next year**

In my opinion, take is a transitive verb. Does "until the end of next year" here act as a noun?

Comment: You've approved an answer that contains a serious error. See my comment to the poster.

Comment: Thank you BillJ, but what do you mean by "a complement of an intransitive verb"?

Comment: Adverbials are **always** optional, but "until the end of the year" is **obligatory** because its omission would make the sentence ungrammatical. Obligatory items are always complements. Complements are not modifiers, so Jay's answer is wrong on two counts.

Comment: ok, I thought complement is sth after "be verb".

Comment: No, definitely not!. Those that occur with "be" are predicative (subjective or objective) but complements can occur all over the place. The most obvious complements are those whose omission would render the sentence ungrammatical, like "until the end of next year" in your example. (we clearly can't say *"a full US economic recovery may take". Remember that obligatory items are **always** complements.

Comment: Thank you so much. Also find a link, just mark as a note :  https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/complements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Federal Reserve chair Jay Powell has warned that a full US economic*
>   *recovery may take until the end of next year*.

No: "take" can be transitive ("take a card"), but in your example it is intransitive.

"Until the end of the year" is a preposition phrase functioning as complement of "take". It has a temporal meaning.

We know it's a complement because it's obligatory; its omission would render the sentence ungrammatical.

Comment: If, instead of "until the end of the year", it said "will take time", would you consider that transitive?

Answer (score -1):

"Until the end of next year" is acting as an adverb. It modifies the verb.

The original sentence is odd wording. I think most English speakers would have said "will LAST until ..." or "will CONTINUE until ..."

Yes, "take" is, or can be, a transitive verb. But just because a verb is transitive doesn't mean that the words that follow it must be the object of the verb. If I said, "Bob will take a cookie", then yes, a cookie is the thing Bob is taking. But if I said, "Bob will take selfishly", "selfishly" is not the thing he is taking. It is an adverb describing how he takes.

Comment: Sorry, the first part of your answer contains an error. "Until the end of next year" is syntactically obligatory and hence can only be a complement. It does **not** modify the verb. Adjuncts (adverbials) are always optional elements.